# Sorting and searching a foreign entity field on a Laravel Livewire table

Tags: laravel

I’ve just implemented a Livewire data table based on the Caleb’s tutorial on Laracasts. Everything works as expected when working with just one model. However I’m stuck trying to apply sorting and searching to a foreign model field.

User model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    use HasRoles;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    /**
    * Get the user's email verified status.
    *
    * @param  string  $value
    * @return string
    */
    public function getEmailVerifiedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        if ($value == null) {
            return "No";
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function getRoleAttribute()
    {
        if($this->roles()->count() > 0) {
            return $this->roles()->first()->name;
        } else {
            return "Usuario registrado";
        }
    }

    public static function search($query)
    {
        return empty($query) ? static::query()
            : static::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    }

}
```

Tried adding another orWhere() clause to the search() method in some ways. None worked. Now I left just the default ones.

Livewire controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Users;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Table extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $perPage;
    public $sortField;
    public $sortAsc;
    public $search;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->perPage = 10;
        $this->sortField = 'name';
        $this->sortAsc = true;
        $this->search = '';
    }

    public function sortBy($field)
    {
        if ($this->sortField === $field) {
            $this->sortAsc = ! $this->sortAsc;
        } else {
            $this->sortAsc = true;
        }

        $this->sortField = $field;
    }

    public function updatingPerPage()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users.table', [
            'users' => \App\User::search($this->search)
                ->with('roles')
                ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc ? 'asc' : 'desc')
                ->paginate($this->perPage),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Livewire view:

```
<div>
    <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col form-inline">
            Mostrar &nbsp;
            <select wire:model="perPage" class="form-control form-control-sm custom-select custom-select-sm">
                <option>10</option>
                <option>100</option>
                <option>1000</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp; registros
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input wire:model="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Buscar usuarios...">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive mb-4" >
        <div class="table-header">
            <table class="table table-sm text-nowrap" role="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="30%">
                            <a wire:click.prevent="sortBy('name')" role="button" href="#">
                                Nombre
                                @include('partials._sort-icon', ['field' => 'name'])
                            </a>
                        </th>
                        <th width="30%">
                            <a wire:click.prevent="sortBy('email')" role="button" href="#">
                                Correo electrónico
                                @include('partials._sort-icon', ['field' => 'email'])
                            </a>
                        </th>
                        <th width="30%">
                            <a wire:click.prevent="sortBy('')" role="button" href="#">
                                Rol
                                @include('partials._sort-icon', ['field' => ''])
                            </a>
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="table-body">
            <table class="table table-sm table-hover text-nowrap" role="grid">
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30%">{{ $user->name }}</td>
                            <td width="30%">{{ $user->email }}</td>
                            <td width="30%">{{ $user->role }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="POST" action="{!! route('backend.users.user.destroy', $user->id) !!}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                    <input name="_method" value="DELETE" type="hidden">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs float-right" role="group">
                                        @can('users.show')
                                            <a href="{{ route('backend.users.user.show', $user->id ) }}" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-xs" title="{{ trans('users.show') }}">
                                                <i class=" fas fa-fw fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        @endcan
                                        @can('users.edit')
                                            <a href="{{ route('backend.users.user.edit', $user->id ) }}" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-xs" title="{{ trans('users.edit') }}">
                                                <i class=" fas fa-fw fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        @endcan
                                        @can('users.destroy')
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-default btn-xs" title="{{ trans('users.delete') }}" onclick="return confirm(&quot;{{ trans('users.confirm_delete') }}&quot;)">
                                                <i class=" fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        @endcan
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="table-footer">
        <div class="text-muted">
            Showing {{ $users->firstItem() }} to {{ $users->lastItem() }} out of {{ $users->total() }} results
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ $users->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Tried also some ways to pass an argument to the sortBy() and [‘field’ => ‘’] on the role column. Now I left them with empty strings.

I know, this issue probably is more related to Laravel than Livewire, but I’ll really appreciate any help.

Update:

Solved using the Laravel Query Builder instead of Eloquent.